# set marker (tag) in vim command

Tags: vim

Usually I type m immediately followed by c to set a marker (tag) c which I can use with 'c to jump to this position.
Now, I try to define a command in vim which sets a marker

```
:command! Setmark mc
```

But with

```
:Setmark
```

I get

```
E14: invalid address
```

because, obviously, c is not a command but rather something like an argument for the command m .
How can I set a valid address for the marker in a vim command/script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap your normal commands under `:normal`, which is an ex-command (the kind of command expected by `:command`.

```
:command! Setmark normal mc
```

---

Alternatively use the proper [`:mark`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%3amark) ex-command:

```
:command! Setmark mark c
```

The help contains the full details.

Comment: Seems to work. Is there a non-normal command equivalent to set marks which, I think, would be preferred for scripts?

Comment: @user429540 Yep, I included that in the answer.